# bs4 cannot pick expected text string?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract article published date using bs4 because newspaper module sometimes works and doesn't at other occasion.

The URL is http://www.popsci.com/ups-tests-drone-deliveries-to-island for example.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

#print (soup.prettify())
date = soup.find('span', {'class':"date"})
print (date)
```

This will show following information.

`<span class="date" data-timestamp="1474907692"><span class="label">posted</span> Sep 26th, 2016 at 12:34pm</span>`

I just need **Sep 26th, 2016 at 12:34pm** portion.

So, I tried,

```
date = soup.find('span',{'class':"date"}, text=(re.compile("Sep")))
```

However, this just returns **None**.

I believe I miss something here but don't know what's wrong.
Could someone help me to guide what I should fix?

Comment: Isn't the text you want in the class called "label"?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
date = soup.find('span', {'class':"date"}).text.replace("posted ", "")
# 'Sep 26th, 2016 at 12:34pm'
```

You might want to wrap it into some `try/catch` block to make it safer.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I'd like to go one step further. I'd like to make this date extract statement as generic as possible so that I can reuse this for other page scraping. So, I tried,

   date = soup.find('span', text=re.compile(r"^Sep$|^Sept|^SEP$"))

However, this does not work.. Just returning **None** again.
What's the best approach here?